# how to prevent data re entering on database on page refresh on laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

I have a POS under development and I noticed that when I reload the page, it re-enters the data. How do you prevent the data from re entering on page reload?

My Controller has this code:

```
public function DoAddSales(Request $request) 
{      
    $rules = [
        'customer_name'=>'required|alpha',
        'or_number'=>'required',
        'payment'=>'required',
    ];  

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validator); 
    } else {
        foreach ($request->input('id_item') as $id) {
            $item_id[] = $id; 
        }

        foreach ($request->input('i_name') as $name) {
            $i_name[] = $name; 
        }

        foreach ($request->input('id_categ') as $categ) {
            $categ_id[] = $categ; 
        }

        foreach ($request->input('quan') as $quan) {
            $quantity[] = $quan; 
        }

        foreach ($request->input('tot') as $total) {
            $each_total[] = $total; 
        }

        $last = sizeof($request->input('id_item'));       
        $i = 0;

        while ($i < $last) { 
            $items = Item::find($item_id[$i]);       
            $sales = new sales;    
            $sales->or = $request->input('or_number');
            $sales->customer_name = $request->input('customer_name');
            $sales->item_id = $item_id[$i];
            $sales->item_name = $i_name[$i];
            $sales->category_id = $categ_id[$i];
            $sales->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $sales->qty = $quantity[$i];
            $sales->total = $each_total[$i];
            $sales->save();

            DB::table('items')->where('id',$item_id[$i])
                ->update(['qty'=> $items->qty - $quantity[$i]]);

            return view ('show_sales')->with(array(
                'name'=>$request->input('customer_name'),
                'or_no'=>$request->input('or_number'),          
                'total'=>$request->input('getItemPrice'),            
                'change'=>$request->input('change'),
                'orders'=>$i_name[$i], 
            ));
            $i++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: redirect after db entries are made

Comment: First of all, methods you use to process something such as saving information, send emails, or something like that, shouldn't return a view. 
It should return a redirect response instead. This way the user shouldn't be able to refresh the page which contains the update/insert code.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

Use **redirect** like following.

Suppose a redirect route like `\view\list`, then you can add the following line at the end of the function as

```
public function DoAddSales(Request $request){
    ...
    // Your code
    ...
    return redirect()->to('\view\list')->with('alert-success','Records saved Successfully');
}
```

**NOTE:** This redirect route must be of `GET` type.